# JsonArray to String array[] initialize in android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, popup

```
 private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EnterVolumeActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        try{


            final String[] arrayValue = new String[] {"200","400","600","800","1000","1200","1400","1600"};

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnterVolumeActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("CHOOSE A VALUE...");

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
                    arrayValue, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            String selectedItem = Arrays.asList(arrayValue).get(i);
                            volumeLtr.setText(selectedItem);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    volumeLtr.setText("");
                }
            });


            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();

        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I referred, how to implement popup listview on online, above code for popup listview.

I got result value from AsyncTask like below format :

```
["200","400","600","800","1000","1200","1400","1600","1800","2000","2200"];
```

Here i have doubt as, how to result value dynamically initialize in array.

```
 final String[] arrayValue = new String[] {"200","400","600","800","1000","1200","1400","1600"};
```

please help for this.

Otherwise how to implement code for popup listview like below result value format.

```
   ["200","400","600","800","1000","1200","1400","1600","1800","2000","2200"];
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject arr=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
List<String> list=new ArrayList();
//If u want to use  array then 

String [] str=new String [arr.length];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
```

list.add(arr.get(i));

str[i]= arr.get(i);
     }